# Ajax url doesn't work for actions in different controller folders

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

1. Please look at the ajax URL hardcoded which works but the usual url(commented) doesn't work! How to specify such url to direct ajax call to different controller folder?
2. Even with hardcoded url I cannot set json data to modal pop up label in the view which calls ajax request. But an alert works fine!

How strange is that or am making any mistakes here?

My Script:

```
$("#img_xx_info").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //url: '@Url.Action("action1","controller2")', //doesnt work
            url: "../controller2/action1",   //works
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(obj.count);//works

         $("#value_xy_Id").val = obj.count;//doesnt work this #value_xy_Id is a part of modal lable

            }
        });       
        $("#myModal").modal('show');  

    });
```

My MVC Structure:

----content

css goes here

----scripts

ajax script goes here ( needs to call controller2/action1 to return json result)
 ----controllers

```
    >A      -controller1controller(action1,2,3..)

    >B      -controller2controller(action1,2,3..) // return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    >C      -controller3controller(action1,2,3..)
```

-------views

```
    >A      -file1.cshtml

    >B      -file1.cshtml

    >C      -file1.cshtml ("#img_xx_info" click event here invokes below scripts + modal popup here to get json into table)
```

Comment: What response do you get back from the server?

Comment: It seems that you are calling this `Url.Action` in the script file. Is that right? If it is, it is not going to work. Script files are not processed by the ASP.NET MVC View engine, so whatever Razor code you put there is not going to be touched and will stay as is. YOu may want to define some js variable in the view, put the URL in there, and then use this variable in your script file.